# How to scale a game designed for iPad to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I made a game using cocos2d for iPad.. Now I have to scale it for iPhone. I tried using scaleX and ScaleY parameters for my GameScene. It scaled the sprites, but I have a lot of hard coded boundaries for my objects which don't get scaled. How can I do the complete scaling of my game??

Answer (score 0):

you have to do something like following

```
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    [yourview setFrame:CGRectMake(400, 208, viewrect.size.width, viewrect.size.height)];
 else 
    [yourview setFrame:CGRectMake(190, 96, viewrect.size.width, viewrect.size.height)];
```

you already done for iPad, so now you need to change else portion
set your view's frame there according to device orientation.